# How to create a method that checks for pattern in string and return the character after the pattern using an ArrayList? (Prompt in description)

Tags: java, arraylist

Method Name - getCharsThatFollowPattern

Prompt and what its supposed to do. Takes a String text and a String pattern as parameters, and returns an ArrayList.  The returned list should contain the character that follows each non-tail occurrence of the pattern in the text. (A non-tail occurrence of the pattern is one that is not at the very end of the text.) The length of the list must be the same as the number of non-tail occurrences of the pattern. The character stored at index n of the list must be the character that followed the nth non-tail occurrence of the pattern.  For example, getCharsThatFollowPattern("abcabdabcab", "ab") should return the ArrayList ['c', 'd', 'c'].

My code is below along with the results.

```
public static ArrayList<Character> getCharsThatFollowPattern (String text, String pattern)
{

    ArrayList<Character> character = new ArrayList<>();

    // String str = text;
    // String findStr = pattern;
    int lastIndex = 0;

    while (lastIndex != -1) {

        lastIndex = text.indexOf(pattern, lastIndex);

        if (lastIndex != -1) {


            lastIndex += pattern.length();
            char c = text.charAt(text.lastIndexOf(pattern) - 1);


            character.add(c);
            }
        }



    return character;
}
```

The results of the code are as follow.

```
 getCharsThatFollowPattern("abcabdabcab", "ab") returns [c,c,c,c];
```

- which is wrong.

```
 getCharsThatFollowPattern("abababa", "aba") returns [b, b];
```

- which is what its supposed to do.

My teacher supplied me with a test case that works but when I tested it myself it does not work.

```
@Test
public void testGetCharsThatFollowPattern ()
{
    ArrayList<Character> list = new ArrayList<Character>();
    list.add('b');
    list.add('b');
    assertEquals(list, 
          PS5Library.getCharsThatFollowPattern("abababa", "aba"));
  }

}
```

I have been scavenging stack overflow and cannot find an answer to my question. Any insights on to why how to fix this would be great. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have a small math error and just need to change the line that assigns c to this:

```
char c = text.charAt(lastIndex);
```

Comment: That throws an index out of range. And if I do

char c = text.charAt(lastIndex - 1); 

It wil print out [b, b , b , b];

Comment: But I do think the issue resides there, because as I was debugging I noticed the indexing was fine. It goes from 3 to 5 to 8 to 11 which would correctly print out [c, d , c]. but its constantly adding c to the arrayList.

Comment: It makes complete sense that I would set it to just lastIndex. because if I have the index of 5 then char c would be the character at the index of 5. so why is it throwing an exception?

Comment: Actually ill just write a catch the exception. Ill accept your answer as correct. thanks!

Comment: Whoops, I missed that exception.  Need to wrap it with a check like this: if(lastIndex < text.length())

Answer (score 1):

You already accepted an answer but the reason why you always added `c` is the following line:

```
char c = text.charAt(text.lastIndexOf(pattern) - 1);
```

You always look for the character after the last occurrence of the pattern. The `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` results from the fact that the text ends with the pattern without subsequent character. The index itself is zero-indexed, so `charAt(5)` tries to access the 6th character of a five-character-long text.

You might ignore the exception or check the length of the text with the index and only call `charAt(index)` if `index < text.length()`. The latter would prevent unnecessary creations of Exceptions and it's better style, too ;-)

Comment: Hmm. Interesting I'll try this when I get home. My way was way harder haha. Thank you. Upvoted this.